# How to edit, compile and read MQL4 files using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, build-automation, mql4

I am trying to automate the editing, compiling and reading of results of MQL4 file using python, are there any tools like selenium but targeted for UI?

Comment: what are the results of the MQL4 file you are talking about? Do you want to parse tester results (or optimization results)? Or do you want to get list of objects on a chart that were generated by some MQL4 code?

Comment: Just the compile results I want to know if it has 0 errors and 0 warnings.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is two things:

- First option: clear the strategy tester logs, use comments in the code with specific string format, copy the logs and parse the data from the comments using python.
- Second option: parse the expert advisor report using Python, from HTML to pandas dataframe for further processing.